# React native App crashes at dismiss of uiviewcontroller

Tags: swift, react-native, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

I have a react-native app. I am using react's version 0.61.4. I am trying to dismiss a UIViewController after showing it with a pod's UI, with code:

```
@objc
class EditProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      UserDetailsManager.editUserInfo(onViewController: self, completionBlock: {success in
        if(success) {
          print("Profile edited");
        }
        let instanceOfCosmoteIdHelper = CosmoteIdHelper();
        instanceOfCosmoteIdHelper.editProfile(success);
        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)        
      }) 
    }
}
```

App crashes after that with console output being like this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid
update: invalid number of rows in section 1. The number of rows contained in an existing section
after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0
moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x180abea48 0x1807e5fa4 0x1809c0e88 0x180df66c4 0x184ce1bc4 0x184ce1680 0x184cf8d5c 0x184cf93c8 0x1015914dc 0x10158b038 0x18451cab8 0x18451d160 0x18447f1d8 0x18451cab8 0x18451d160 0x18443a310 0x18443ff04 0x184439b58 0x184436f98 0x184525dc0 0x184527790 0x184529d74 0x184fb9e68 0x184529cd4 0x18452a168 0x184529bbc 0x184529e24 0x10158145c 0x100cb38d0 0x100cb3b90 0x18451cb98 0x18451d5b8 0x1844366c4 0x1844364a4 0x18444064c 0x18443ac44 0x18453ea80 0x18453bc2c 0x184543220 0x184650eb4 0x1845431b0 0x184fb9b20 0x184543018 0x18443a70c 0x18443ff04 0x184439b58 0x1844373c8 0x18452b4f4 0x184fb9e68 0x18452b370 0x184fb9e68 0x18452b024 0x18452462c 0x18452a614 0x18452a168 0x18452c878 0x100cb3ad0 0x101583d94 0x101587864 0x10154ccc8 0x10130e680 0x1012c7a8c 0x1033057fc 0x103306bd8 0x103314c34 0x180a3c5e4 0x180a375d8 0x180a36adc 0x18a9bc328 0x184b31ae0 0x100cab328 0x1808c0360)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```